# SQL Server Execute with command line tool returns missing field information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cmd, command-line-tool, xp-cmdshell

I want to execute a command line utility using xp_cmdshell and return the results in CSV format for processing in a SQL Server table.

The command line with options/parameters:

```sh
tasklist /v /FO:CSV
```

The SQL script line is:

```sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist /v /FO:CSV'
```

The returned column names are:

```
Image Name, PID, Session Name, Session#, Mem Usage, Status, User Name, CPU Time, Window Title
```

It is important for me to take the "Window Title" info, but the  window title always returns `"N/A"` when I run command line using xp_cmdshell. When I run code directly in Windows Command Prompt, *(cmd.exe)*, it returns the "Window Title" information I require.

Comment: Just like the last question - tsql is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: When I run `tasklist /v /FO:CSV` in a `cmd.exe` window, it returns `"N/A"` as the 'Window Title'.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server runs as a background service, and so has no desktop.  And it can't see the "window title" of processes running in other sessions.